# How to import CSV with locations in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to import a CSV file in a BigQuery table.
In my CSV I got two columns: one with latitude and another with longitude.
Something like this:

```
id,name,lat,lng
1234,"Mario",12.12414,88.123141
4124,"Luigi",72.12415,1.123513
```

How do I have to format the point location to be recognized by BigQuery to be a GEOGRAPHY type?
I cannot find an answer in the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data

I've tried this formats without success:

```
POINT(<lng> <lat>)
POINT(<lng>, <lat>)
(<lat> <lng>)
(<lat>, <lng>)
```

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant answer doesn't quite answer your question since BigQuery does allow for the GEOGRAPHY datatype. Have you since managed to import GIS data directly (e.g. using `bq load`)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually create the schema and set the type of the column as "GEOGRAPHY" as below sample below you import the csv as POINT(lng lat)

```
[
  {
    "description": "Outlet Code",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "outlet_code",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "description": "Outlet Name",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "outlet_name",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "description": "Location",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "location",
    "type": "GEOGRAPHY"
  }
]
```

Comment: or as command line flags, `bq load --schema code:STRING,name:STRING,location:GEOGRAPHY`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to load your CSV file into BigQuery as is, but then you can use [geography functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions) to get geography objects out of your data as in example below

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(longitude, latitude)
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thank you! I forget to mention that I want to plot those locations on a map in DataStudio, can I?

Comment: i think he is asking how to create the table from csv with GEOGRAPHY data type field

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't easy to find. But the Answer is here regarding loading CSV. There is a section on the Geography type. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv

The following list shows examples of valid data:

WKT: POINT(1 2)
GeoJSON: { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [1, 2] }
Hex encoded WKB: 0101000000feffffffffffef3f0000000000000040

The POINT(1,2) you tried should work according to this. But I wonder if GeoJSON is better? It just seems like this format is a heavy favorite with this kind of data.

Comment: It should not mater for points, choose WKT or GeoJson depending on your preference. For lines and polygons there is semantic difference - choose GeoJson if your data comes from planar Geometry world, choose WKT if data comes from spherical Geography world.